# Missing print panel in KDE Plasma system settings

Tags: printing, plasma, kde5

I just switched my Ubuntu 20.04 installation from Gnome to KDE. Everything is going well except the Printers panel is missing from System Settings. According to various documentation I've found, it should appear between Power Management and Removable Storage, but KDE Connect is there instead. I've looked around for ways to install it and everything I see assumes it's just there by default. I like Plasma but I'd like to be able to control my printers without logging out and logging back in with Gnome, or using cups on the command line. Any advice?

Comment: How did you install KDE; did you install all of it? selected parts of it? or all of the Kubuntu desktop?  Details of what you installed will allow us to see if you missed components are that included with `kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I installed with apt install kde-standard. BTW I also did kcmshell5 --list and there's nothing printer-related there either.

Comment: Install what you want; you installed https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kde-standard which is parts only as it states, you could have installed https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kde-full for more but it's still less than the full Kubuntu installed set https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kubuntu-desktop (which includes printing capabilities that aren't KDE related packages)

Comment: Thanks. I'm installing kubuntu-desktop now so I have the complete package, but I'm curious - if kde-standard just gave me parts, are there parts that I could install that would include the printer control? Kubuntu-desktop seems like a big installation if all I want to add is printer support.

PS - installing kbuntu-desktop fixed the problem, and probably numerous others. I now have a printer panel in System Settings. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you're looking for the the `print-manager` package.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt install print-manager
```

This is a recommended package of the `kubuntu-desktop` package. [guiverc's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1357896/1586374) explains in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous packages that contain parts of KDE, some contain more than others.

- kde-standard: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kde-standard  (what you installed, selected parts of KDE only)
- kde-full: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kde-full (a more complete KDE group of KDE packages)
- kubuntu-desktop: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kubuntu-desktop  (what the Kubuntu team include which include more than just KDE components)

KDE packages contain KDE only; printing is included in other non-KDE packages (eg. kubuntu add what they feel you need in `kubuntu-desktop`).

Reading the package (eg. `kubuntu-desktop` you'll note it split into parts

- *depends*; these are required
- *recommended* - what Kubuntu recommend which include CUPS or printing functionality
- *suggests* - Kubuntu don't have any listed here

If you want to install the individual components, you're free to, and can look at the `kubuntu-desktop` package for clues as to what they add on top of the base Ubuntu system.